# Should i use play framework or normal Java EE

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, playframework

Am planning to start a website that I will use commercially. I recently have heard of the Play framework and it looks good. But am not sure if I should use it or not. I know java, jsp, servlets and struts 1.

I don't know how stable that framework is? Should I go with a native Java EE application or should I use Play?

Comment: play is very much in the development/early stages, so you will probably have some growing pains with it.

Comment: disagree that play is in the development stages. Play 1.0 was development, but even then it was stable. Play 1.1 was about adding features, play 1.2 has added a lot of nice to have's, but there was nothing in 1.1 I couldn't achieve. Play is now very stable. It has also been around for well over 2 years now, so although not as mature as some, it is stable and more importantly, does not have the bloat of other frameworks.

Comment: Just curious, how can this be an off topic? qstn is not even subjective.

Comment: @Mat, JoseK, Jonas, bmargulies, John Saunders :If u dont like the question dont answer it, you dont need to mark it closed

Comment: This is a shopping rekommandation request. Those tend to get closed quickly.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to have a rapid return on investment play is your friend.
Within days of using it you can get a web site up and running (which even for an experienced Java EE developer is a bit of a challenge). I think you need to balance you requirements with the advantages of play.

Check this interesting post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376732/what-is-pro-and-contra-of-using-play-framework

Play is always gaining more momentum and there are already a few commercial websites using it http://www.playframework.org/community/testimonials.

I would also add that play is fun to develop with which will also add to your productivity!

Answer (score 8):

Play is stable. It now has some big reference sites, including the guardian.co.uk and more and more sites are springing up all the time. It is very easy to develop in, has its own dedicated hosting service (if required) and has a very active community.

As for whether you should use it or not, is too subjective a question to answer fairly. I use it, and would always now do so over a Java EE application, but my needs (quick, clean, not bloated) may not be the same drivers as yours.

I would suggest doing a proof of concept in both technologies, and see which one suites your needs the best. If you cant afford the time to do a proof of concept, maybe you should stick to what you know?

Answer (score 1):

Part of the answer is in the answer to the question: What is the purpose of this website?

Personally, I would stick with more well-used frameworks like Java EE (version 5 & 6 have a LOT less cruft than the older versions) or something like Spring or Seam. If you are going for a simple site, maybe look into [JBoss Seam](http://www.jboss.com/products/seam/).

Answer (score 1):

Play does indeed look nice and clean. From my experience using any new framework will bring its pros and cons. Play might be buggy, you seem to know Java EE. It really depends on what you want to do and how much you're willing to invest in learning something new.

In my opinion it is always possible to transition to some new way of delivering your site content. It's healthy to keep experimenting with new frameworks, but wiser to build business on a framework you know. That way the bottleneck wont be the technology.

Comment: Time changes everything. Today play is good, and I believe it will become even better in the near future.